# OpenGL draw rectangle composed of lines with vertex array

Tags: opengl

So I have a vertex array batcher, and I want to use it to render rectangles that are lines instead of filled in. Currently I am using `glPolyGonMode()`, but since my "shapes" are all uploaded to the graphics card as triangles, I get a line running down the middle of my rectangle, like this:[image]

Obviously this is happening because there are two triangles to a rectangle. But I want to render only the rectangle without the middle line. How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with triangle list, triangle is the essential primitive to build up 3D models. you need two triangles to build up the rectangle.

If you don't want the middle line

1. Use GL_QUADS, this is the easist way to your request, but be aware that GL_QUADS was [deprecate from core OpenGL 3.1](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Primitive)
2. Use LINE_LOOP instead of triangles to build up your rectangle

Draw with GL_QUADS:

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS) ;
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.5, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.5, 0.5, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.5, 0.0, 0.0);
glEnd() ;
```

Draw with LINE_LOOP:

```
glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP) ;
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.5, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.5, 0.5, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.5, 0.0, 0.0);
glEnd() ;
```

Comment: What do you mean line list?

Comment: I mean lines, 4 lines make up a rectangle.

Comment: In theory, drawing quads (not triangles) in wireframe mode will produce the same result. But I never tried it (never wanted to, either).

Comment: @yes, I forgot there is quad type in OpenGL, will update my answer later. thanks!

Comment: @keltar draw with GL_QUADS work, and GL_LINE_LOOP also works, I updated my answer, thanks!